# Are the properties names returned from this loop valid to be used in jQuery css() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to convert CSS string to a valid jQuery css() method properties/values. Example ,

```
function applyCss(itemtochange){


    var $style = 'color: rgb(69, 69, 69); line-height: 85px; height: 85px; padding-right: 15px; border-radius: 0px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 0px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);'; 
    var $convertstyle = $style.split(';');

    $.each($convertstyle,function(index,val){

        if(val){
            var $splitv = val.split(':');
            var $property = $splitv[0];
            var $value = $splitv[1];

            $(itemtochange).css($property ,$value);
        }

    });

}
```

The question is , are all  returned properties names valid and can be used in jQuery css() method or do I need to "massage" the loop ?

**Note: I cant use attr style since the element has style applied to and the CSS is saved in DB , so I can end up having same properties applied to element multiple times. Please try to answer the actual question. Are the properties names returned from the loop valid to be used in css() method**

Comment: You can avoid this problem entirely by putting those style rules in a class and then just using `addClass()` on the required element. Any solution you use here will just end up hacking a string which will be ugly and extremely fragile.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, that would be ideal if this is just a simple apply function once thing , I am working on menu generator so  add/remove class name would not work here as expected.

Comment: Well to answer the question, you'll get the same output you enter as input. So if the property names and values in the string are valid CSS then you will get a valid outcome. However, as I mentioned above this is not an ideal solution, one for which I'm sure there is a better way. However we would need more details on exactly it is you're trying to do. All the information you've given anyone so far is 'I can't do that'

Comment: If you are working on  menu generator where does string come from? Using an object would be much simpler and just pass that object to `css()` method

Comment: When you **set** with `css()` it will maintain existing inline and only update/modify what is in new property/values. I've done numerous projects like this though and using strings is usually last resort when you can easily pass one object with numerous properties to `css()`

Comment: @charlietfl care to answer and show an example of storing the css object instead ?

Comment: See this quick example https://jsfiddle.net/ptcapp2L/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the existing style and then set a new one:
Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sesn/5n5e27te/

```
var target = $("#target");
target.attr("style", target.attr("style") + "; " + yourString);
```

Comment: cant use that , element already has inline style and this data is saved so I will end up with lots of duplicated styles. the style must be clean

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the needle you use for the split. The split functions leaves a whitespace behind, that's why it's not working. Here's a working codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKdXGv

```
function applyCss(itemtochange){


var $style = 'color: rgb(69, 69, 68); line-height: 85px; height: 85px; padding-right: 15px; border-radius: 0px; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 25, 255, 1); '; 
var $convertstyle = $style.split('; ');

$.each($convertstyle,function(index,val){

    if(val){
        var $splitv = val.split(':');
        var $property = $splitv[0];
        var $value = $splitv[1];

        $(itemtochange).css($property ,$value);
    }

});
}
```

Comment: I never said that the function does not work , question is are the properties returned valid as they are http://prntscr.com/bfiaeh